# R: string vector, finding values of indeices smaller than a certain number

Tags: r

could anyone kindly help me with the error message below?

```
list <- c("apple","bee","cat","dog","egg","frog","goat","hippo","iguana")

list[1:5]
# [1] "apple" "bee"    "cat"    "dog"    "egg"
```

However,

```
list[<5]
# Error: unexpected '<' in "list[<"
```

Thank you.

Comment: What did you want `list[<5]` to do?

Comment: I think you want `list[seq_along(list)<5]`  As you didn't provide anything on the lhs of `<`, the error message showed up

Comment: you probably shouldn't assign the name list to atomic vectors as that might get confusing later on.

Comment: `list[1:(5-1)]` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need either a numeric index (in the OP's first example) or logical index to subset the 'list'.  To create a logical index, we can compare the sequence of 'list' elements with the index 5.

```
seq_along(list)<5
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

and using this index, we can get the elements that corresponds to TRUE values

```
list[seq_along(list)<5]
#[1] "apple" "bee"   "cat"   "dog"
```

---

Regarding the error message, if we type

```
<5
```

on the console

> Error: unexpected '<' in "<"

So, it needs a value on the lhs of `<`